# Craft Commerce: Tax Code Field

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Can anyone tell me if the Tax Code field in Craft Commerce is able to be validated? I'd  be using it for UK VAT Reg numbers.

I just want to check how it can currently be used. Is it just a field to store the tax code information or can it be used to perform validations.

Comment: What Tax Code field are you referring to?  Something on the front-end?  If so, you can do whatever validation you want.  The backend has concepts of Tax Categories, Tax Rates and Tax Zones.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I should have asked if "out of the box does it come with tax validation". Doing some research the answer seems to be no and that I would have to add this in myself.